# Get variable from loop in Render into componentDidMount() in ReactJS and put this variable in query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, leaflet

I have a loop in the render that rotates an array of coordinates to position the markers on the map.

```
{coords.map(({ lat, lng }, index) => (code here and etc))}
```

I want into componentDidMount to replace query parameters with that variable from the loop **index + 1**

Before Render I have componentDidMount with the query and response from the database server.

I try to crate varibale with name "id" who = (index + 1) but I don't know how to import into my query.

The code from componentDidMount is:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let id = (index + 1);

    const url = "http://192.168.0.1:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=4&daysForward=8";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ dataAPI: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
    this.setState({ temp: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
    this.setState({ dats: data.aladinModel[0], loading: false });
  }
```

**I want id=4 to be replaced with id=id variable..**

**How can I do that ?**

Comment: What is the specification of '4'? is that the length of the array?

Comment: 4 is id on the database

Comment: Are you looking for string manipulation?

Comment: Can I get example ?

Comment: append the index to to the function `async componentDidMount(idx) {}` the problem is, that the loop with your index variable is faster then your async task to read it out

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like a string manipulation? 
Eg:

```js
const myid = 4;
const url = `http://192.168.0.1:8000/?date=2019-10-20&id=${myid}&daysForward=8`;
console.log(url);
```

Comment: :D No man, down in render I want myid = (index + 1) .... this index is down in render.
I want to get this variable from the loop from the render in component. But this index is above   below ...